# Katz/Lindell Problem 2.2 - Purpose of proof where you redefine the key space?

Tags: deterministic-encryption, probabilistic-encryption

I am self-studying by using "Introduction to Modern Cryptography: Principles and Protocols" (2nd edition).

I am looking at the following problem.

> Prove that, by redefining the key space, we may assume that $Enc$ is
> deterministic without changing $Pr[C = c | M = m]$ for any $m$, $c$.

The question seems to be asking "Prove that if we change a non-deterministic encryption algorithm to a deterministic one, the probability a particular cipher text will result from encrypting a chosen message will not change".

However, if we make an algorithm deterministic, then it can only have 1 output instead of choosing randomly between multiple.

So, we must expand the number of keys (as shown in [Katz/Lindell Problem 2.2](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/51455/katz-lindell-problem-2-2)).

My question is: What is the purpose/value of a proof like this? Yes, we have proved that $Enc$ can be deterministic, but only at the cost of changing the key-space, which seems like a very fundamental / important part of the scheme anyways.

Comment: Deterministic encryption certainly has its merits. Note that the question does not require that $c' \neq c''$ for $m' = m''$